# How to handle spamming campaigns

Tags: discussion

We seem to have a few companies that are going mad with posting links to an appExchange tool that they have created which may actually be suitable for an answer to the question and on being prompted have at least disclosed affiliation to the company in the answer.

I am thinking that we have 2 options - a. just close them off, b. encourage them to show exactly how their tool will answer the question.

I have tried b. on this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/189029/21181), but should we just follow approach a?

Comment: Very interested to see the community's opinion on this!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We've been quite strict in deleting these as far as I'm aware. Both from the community and moderators acting on spam flags.

Most product advertising answers are very brief and redirect to appExchange or the vendor website, without thus providing much objective insight into the product and why it would be a good solution to the question asked.

Like you suggest, if more information would be included in product promoting answers, I'd personally not be against them by definition.